# How i make responsive grid template

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is my tried jsFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/bw0etr21/

there is three block `A`,`B`,`C`. I have applied some grid property on these blocks.
`A`,`B` is in row and `C` is in last.I need to make it responsive.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  /* we can`t change this css property */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  /* we can`t change this css property */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
 @media (max-width:800px){
  .wrapper{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  }
}

/* we can`t change this css property */
.a{
  grid-column: span 3; 
}
.b{
  grid-column:span 3;
}
.c{
  grid-column: span 6
}
/* we can`t change this css property */
.box {
  background-color: #20262e;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
</div>
```

The output should be all block in one columns when we decrease window size below the 800px.

The required output should be like this image link. https://i.ibb.co/Mck9vJx/required-output.png

pls let me know if more info. required. Thank you.

Comment: Please add your code also here.

Comment: i have give my jsFiddle code and what you need

Comment: it's not enough, if the link is broken the question is useless. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bw0etr21/

Comment: i have added code

Comment: You have to clearly mention how the boxes should behave when you resize the windows